# Implementing \lefttorightarrow from mathabx without importing the other symbols

Tags: mathabx

I am trying to implement this code taken from https://mathoverflow.net/q/64544/101848:

```
\usepackage{mathabx,epsfig}
\def\acts{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\righttoleftarrow$}}}
```

so that `G\acts X` yields

[image: 2]

The problem is that loading `mathabx` has the side effect of importing all symbols from mathabx. For example, it changes the default LaTeX `\to`, which is [image], to the symbol [image]. A similar change happens to the default LaTeX `\mapsto` and it also changes the default LaTeX `\in`.

How could I have what the `\acts` command does without loading the rest of the `mathabx` symbols?

Comment: Be aware that `epsfig` only exists for compatibility of 25+ year old documents. Don't load it in new documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The importing code can be improved to use the font at any size. Also the definition of `\acts` can be improved to make a symbol that correctly scales in subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
     <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11>  mathb10
  <11->     mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lefttorightarrow}{3}{mathb}{"FC}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\righttoleftarrow}{3}{mathb}{"FD}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\looparrow}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\looparrow@{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\looparrow@}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1#2$}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\acts}{\looparrow{\righttoleftarrow}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\looparrow{\lefttorightarrow}}

\begin{document}

$G\acts X$

$X\foo G$

$A_{G\acts X}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you don't need the reverse symbol, but it comes almost for free.

Don't use `\def` and you'll be happier.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but I would be *very* unhappy without `\def`.  But thorough, complete answer as usual +1.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @StevenB.Segletes . Isn't it the same on this case to either use `\def` or `\newcommand`?

Comment: What is the `graphicx` package for?

Comment: @ElíasGuisado With `\def` you’re not informed whether the command already exists and you can incur into seroius and weird problems. Since the code uses `\reflectbox`, the `graphicx`  package is needed. Not `epsfig` that is obsolete.

Comment: @ElíasGuisado `\newcommand` does extra checking to make sure the definition does not already exist.  If it does, `\renewcommand` is required.  So there are two places where I would miss `\def` if it did not exist: 1) where I reuse a macro as an intermediate variable.  In such cases, I need extra logic to determine whether to use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` (basically, extra typing to initialize the macro), and 2) for delimited arguments such as `\def#1\relax{}`, where the argument is not one token nor group, but a set of tokens up to the point where `\relax` is found.  I use that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The ⟳ symbol (Clockwise gapped circle arrow) is also in `unicode-math` (and the legacy packages `stix` and `stix2`) as `\cwgapcirclearrow`.  You can therefore use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\[ G \cwgapcirclearrow X \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

To import only this one symbol from a font that has it (such as STIX Two Math, XITS Math or New Computer Modern Math), you can use the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[ range = \cwgapcirclearrow,
                             Scale = MatchUppercase ]

\begin{document}
\[ G \cwgapcirclearrow X \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon Math + STIX Two Math sample]

Answer (score 0):

Mimicking what is done in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/150120, I have come with the following code for the preamble which solves the problem:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\righttoleftarrow}{3}{mathb}{"FD}

\def\acts{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\righttoleftarrow$}}}
```

The six first lines of code are taken from the `mathabx.sty` file available at CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathabx/texinputs.

The `"FD` code for `\righttoleftarrow` was found looking for it in the `mathabx.dcl` file (also available in the last link).

I am posting this answer because the six first lines of code above are not exactly the same ones as those from the quoted TSE answer. The ones here are for `mathb` whereas the ones from the other TSE answer are for `matha`. I copied at first the code from the other TSE answer and it took me a while before realizing a little change was needed.

Comment: If you convert your code *snippet* into a working example, I'm sure you will get more votes.